# greater values in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a searchbox where the user can search for a property. And in the searchbox there are two select boxes. One for minimum price, and one for maximum price.

How would the query look like if the user chooses minimum price 10 000 and maximum price 1 000 000.

Here is my code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
 SELECT * FROM property WHERE price > '%{$_POST['pricemin']}%' AND price < '%{$_POST['pricemax']}%'
```

Comment: Bobby Tables, anyone? If your param is properly sanitized, you can use `BETWEEN` for this test.

Comment: `%` works better with `LIKE`, just make sure you are placing numbers, not strings.

Comment: Seems you forget less than for pricemax.

Comment: Please don't use code like this on a production website. You will get hacked with an SQL injection extremely quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, never put user-entered values directly into a query.  You're asking for SQL injection attacks. And second, why are you trying to do a wildcard match (`%`) on numbers?

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM property WHERE price BETWEEN $min AND $max;
```

Comment: "You're asking for SQL injection attacks" +1

Comment: I have a function called db_escape that I'm using, so thats not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can't do comparisons using `%value%` unless you use `LIKE`. Second, you should really use prepared statements:

```
if (isset($_POST['pricemin'], $_POST['pricemax'])) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM property WHERE price > ? AND price < ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($_POST['pricemin'], $_POST['pricemax']));
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Example is given for PDO; if you don't have PDO or mysqli, start using it!

Answer (score 0):

Ok you need to escape your variables for a start so try this

```
$pricemin = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pricemin']);
$pricemax = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pricemax']);
```

And then I think you missed a less than

```
SELECT * FROM property WHERE price > '$pricemin' AND price < '$pricemax'
```

But you should look into mysqli if you're using databases with php http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php as `mysql_real_escape_string()` and other mysql functions have been depreciated.